# VBA Excel find exact value of a cell, not just part of it

Tags: excel, vba, find

I have the following code:

```
Set User = AD_USERS.Range("D:D").Find(What:=wVal)
```

Where wVal is the value I'm looking for. It's the name of a user that can be like "Ecr484348" or "gh8644". My question is, how can I use find to look for a total coincidence when i'm looking for the name of a user?

I know that if I use `xlWhole` it looks for a whole coincidence but If `wVal = "Ecr"` is going to give me that it found "Ecr484348" and I don't want that. I want that only if you do `wVal = "Ecr484348"` gives you that it found the value, I mean I don't want it to work only using some part of the user name.

Sorry if anything is not well explained, I'll answer if there are any questions.
Thank you so much for your answers!

PS: If I use `xlWhole` like in the following code:

```
Set User = AD_USERS.Range("D:D").Find(What:=wVal, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

It throws me an error 9, and I don't know why.

PS2: I add the whole code here:

```
Dim wrdTbl As Table
    'Set the Word table
    With ActiveDocument
        If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count >= 1 Then
            Set wrdTbl = .Tables(InputBox("Table # to copy? There are " & .Tables.Count & " tables to choose from."))
        End If
    End With

    Dim AD_UsersPath As String
    AD_UsersPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Comparar Columnas VBA\Animales.xlsx"
    Dim AD_USERS As Object
    Set AD_USERS = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    AD_USERS.Visible = False
    AD_USERS.Application.Workbooks.Open AD_UsersPath
    
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = wrdTbl.Columns(1).Cells.Count 

    Dim I As Integer
    For I = 1 To LastRow
        wVal = wrdTbl.Cell(I + 1, 1)
        wVal = Left(wVal, Len(wVal) - 2) 
        Set User = AD_USERS.Range("D:D").Find(What:=wVal)
        If User Is Nothing Then
            wrdTbl.Cell(I + 1, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed 
        Else
            wrdTbl.Cell(I + 1, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorWhite 
        End If
    Next I
    
    AD_USERS.Quit
    Set AD_USERS = Nothing
```

Comment: And how exactly have you implemented `xlWhole`? I don't see it in your code yet.

Comment: It's not the default option in find? Or how can I implement it? Because if I use ```Set User = AD_USERS.Range("D:D").Find(What:=wVal, LookAt:=xlWhole)``` it gives me an error 9.

Comment: `Range.Find` is peculiar in the sense that it will use the last used settings in the next search. Therefor it's good to be more specific and to include `xlWhole`. The error does not come from implementing `xlWhole` as far as I can see, but is probably caused by a faulty call to your worksheet. Are you sure the `CodeName` for "AD_USERS" is correct? Also, how do you `Dim` "wVal" and where do you assing a value?

Comment: I added my whole code in the question, I don't ```Dim``` "wVal" as it changes because Word tables have an extra character I want to delete.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but how can I change the code to use ```Find``` correctly? Sorry I don't know exactly how to change it :/

Comment: Assign a `Worksheet` variable and use the `Range.Find` method on that =)

Comment: You are calling Excel from Word-`AD_USERS` is the object name for the Excel Application, but not for the active Workbook. You'll need a variable for the active workbook and/or ActiveSheet. Not tested, but something like `Set User = AD_USERS.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").Find(What:=wVal, LookAt:=xlWhole)` should work. Also, looking at your code, you just want to check if a specific value exists in Column D or not, so I suggest you to use COUNTIF better than `Find`. COUNTIF will return 0 if nothing is found, 1 or more if there is any match. Check `WorksheetFunction.Countif`

Comment: I see, ```Set User = AD_USERS.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").Find(What:=wVal, LookAt:=xlWhole)``` gives me an error. How can I assign a ```Worksheet``` variable in Word vba?

Comment: Yes CountIf can work better I think, so for CountIf to work, I should use ```User = AD_USERS.Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(Range("D:D"), wVal)```? because it throws me an error too

Comment: Okay, I found this goes correct: ```User = AD_USERS.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(AD_USERS.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D:D"), wVal)```, I'll check if it works good and if so I'll close this question, thank you so much!

Comment: @Raúl Your question was lacking clarity. You never mentioned in the beginning that you're writing this code in word VBA and you're using late binding to access excel. You need to define `xlWhole` or use its value directly, which is `1`.

Comment: Try using `Set User = AD_USERS.Range("D:D").Find(What:=wVal, LookAt:=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line `Set User = AD_USERS.Range("D:D").Find(What:=wVal)` to

```
Set User = AD_USERS.Range("D:D").Find(What:=wVal, LookAt:=1)
```

When you are using late binding to create and excel application from word vba, then excel constants (e.g. `xlWhole`) are not defined by default. They are only defined if you add the excel reference to your project. You can either define it yourself with `Dim xlWhole As Integer: xlWhole = 1` or just use the value `1` whenever you need to use this constant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that gave me an error 9, so finally I decided to change the line to ```User = AD_USERS.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(AD_USERS.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D:D"), wVal)``` and use ```CountIf``` instead.

Comment: I am glad you got it sorted. But always keep in mind my point about cross-application constants when using late binding.

Comment: I'll keep it, thank you! However I couldn't find why the error happened when I use LookAt in my line. But as it works with CountIf I'll work with that.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that you have not declared `User`. You need to either, `Dim User as Object` or better `Dim User as AD_USERS.Range` and I believe this should work.

Comment: Always add `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules so the compiler warns you when you don't declare variables. To do this manually, go to Tools/Options and check the Require Variable Declaration box.

Comment: Oh thank you, I didn't know you could do that. I'll add it to my new macros from now on. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Foxfire And Burns And Burns suggested I used `CountIf` at the end so it worked better and I solved my error using `Find`.
The line is now:

```
User = AD_USERS.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(AD_USERS.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D:D"), wVal)
```

Thank you everyone for your answers!

Comment: The reason your previous line was raising error it's what @superSymmetry mentioned. You are using late binding, so variables like `xlWhole` are not being recognized. Something like `AD_USERS.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").Find(What:=wVal, LookAt:=1)` should work. But glad you made it work!

Comment: Thank you, probably it was that, I'll check it!